# Rust, Copy Trait not working with a type when it uses generic

Tags: pointers, generics, rust, copy

Rust won't compile the following:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct WhateverStruct<T> {
    field : T
}

trait WhateverStructTrait<T> {
    fn to(self) -> WhateverStruct<T>;
}
impl<T> WhateverStructTrait<T> for *mut WhateverStruct<T> {
    fn to(self) -> WhateverStruct<T> {
        unsafe {* self }
    }
}

fn test() {
    let x = WhateverStruct { field : 7u32 };
    let _y = x;
    let _z = x;
    println!("Copying is fine");
}

fn main() {
    test();
}
```

It complains on the  unsafe `{* self }` part saying that

> `*self` has type `WhateverStruct<T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

However, it quite clearly does implement the copy trait.  The test function has no errors.  If you change `struct WhateverStruct<T> { field : T }` into `struct WhateverStruct { field : u32 }` and remove the `<T>` from the rest of the code, everything compiles and runs just fine.  So Rust isn't liking the generic.

Here you can see on the playground : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5d5c3a0f0e6e0153ec286ce38f0f3a2d

Is this a bug?  Is there a work around?

Comment: When you use `#[derive(Copy)]` on `Foo<T>`, `Foo<T>` still only implements `Copy` if `T` does. Just add the bound `T: Copy` to your `impl`.

Comment: @SCappella My particular use case, the structure is actually `struct WhateverStructPtr { field : *mut T }` I just didn't want to overcomplicate my question.  And WhateverStructPtr needs to be Copy even when T isn't.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Implement `Clone` and `Copy` manually. It should be pretty trivial.

Comment: Something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a48d3b6299d275fd5ad9f4179d1fa427).

Comment: @SCappella Thanks, I had to look up the trait definitions so I didn't get it as fast as you :)  If you'd like to post your answer, I'll accept it.  Someone else might get this error message.

Comment: @SCappella Also that is a pretty misleading error message.  It would be better to say `*self has type WhateverStruct<T>, which only implements the Copy trait when T : Copy.  Consider explicitly implementing Copy on WhateverStruct or requiring <T: Copy>` .  Is there someone to make that suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For any generic type `Foo<T>` when you derive `Copy` and `Clone`, the traits always have `T` bound to be `Copy` or `Clone` respectively. Sometimes, though you don't actually need `T` to implement those traits for the struct as a whole to be `Copy` or `Clone`.

An example of this is the following struct.

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Foo<T> {
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}
```

If we look at the code that the derive generates ([`cargo-expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) works for that purpose) we get something like

```
use std::prelude::v1::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;

struct Foo<T> {
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}

#[automatically_derived]
#[allow(unused_qualifications)]
impl<T: ::core::marker::Copy> ::core::marker::Copy for Foo<T> {}

#[automatically_derived]
#[allow(unused_qualifications)]
impl<T: ::core::clone::Clone> ::core::clone::Clone for Foo<T> {
    #[inline]
    fn clone(&self) -> Foo<T> {
        match *self {
            Foo {
                _marker: ref __self_0_0,
            } => Foo {
                _marker: ::core::clone::Clone::clone(&(*__self_0_0)),
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at just the implementation of `Copy` (and cleaning up things a bit) it's

```
impl<T: Copy> Copy for Foo<T> {}
```

So even though `Foo<T>` doesn't need `T` to be `Copy`, it restricts it anyway.

In these cases, you'll want to simply implement `Copy` and `Clone` yourself. There's a fairly trivial implementation that works as long as the actual fields of the struct are `Copy`.

```
struct Foo<T> {
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> Copy for Foo<T> {}

impl<T> Clone for Foo<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        *self
    }
}
```